# Htaccess - RewriteCond: only php as file extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to apply a rewrite condition, so that only *.php files are affected:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example.php [L]
```

The first condition here does not seem to work for files inside a directory like www.test.com/test/example.php (only for www.test.com/example.php).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^\.]+\.php$ /example.php [L,NC]
```